# migrate hibernate 5 to hibernate 6 render Custom predicates

Tags: java, database, hibernate-criteria

I'm trying to migrate from hibernate 5 to hibernate 6. Everything works as exptected, except for custom Expressions.
In hibernate 5 it was possible to create custom Expression (e.g: RlikeExpression that renders as $1 RLIKE $2 for mysql and regexp_substring ($1, $2) IS NOT NULL for hsql)

My goal is to be able to add a Predicate, the same way as LIKE. (or eventually to create custom orderBy Expressions) All I need is a way to render myself what I need to write in the query.
E.G :

```
criteriaQuery.where(new RLikePredicate(criteriaBuilder, from.get("COLUMN"), "REGEX"));
OR
criteriaQuery.orderBy(new MyOrderExpression(criteriaBuilder, ...)); // this creates a case/when SQL query thanks to the render(RenderingContext) method.
```

How is it possible to achieve the same in hibernate 6.
Here is my RLikePredicate (I know it's not pretty, but it works)

In my HSQLDialect (for junit testing)

```
public class HSQLIntBooleanDialect extends HSQLDialect {
    public HSQLIntBooleanDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("rlike", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "regexp_substring (?1, ?2) "));
    }
}
```

In my MYSQL Dialect (for production)

```
public class MySQL5IntBooleanDialect extends MySQL5Dialect {
    public MySQL5IntBooleanDialect() {
        super();
        registerFunction("rlike", new SQLFunctionTemplate(StandardBasicTypes.INTEGER, "(?1 RLIKE ?2)"));
    }
}
```

And now, the part I'm having problems to migrate :

```
package fr.cstb.doef.dao.expression;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.CriteriaBuilderImpl;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.ParameterRegistry;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.Renderable;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.RenderingContext;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.expression.LiteralExpression;
import org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.predicate.AbstractSimplePredicate;

import javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder;
import javax.persistence.criteria.Expression;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.function.Function;

@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "WeakerAccess", "UnusedReturnValue"})
public class RLikePredicate extends AbstractSimplePredicate implements Serializable {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(RLikePredicate.class);

    private final Expression<String> matchExpression;
    private final Expression<String> pattern;

    public RLikePredicate(
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
        Expression<String> matchExpression,
        Expression<String> pattern) {
        this(criteriaBuilder, matchExpression, pattern, null);
    }

    public RLikePredicate(
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
        Expression<String> matchExpression,
        String pattern) {
        this(criteriaBuilder, matchExpression, new LiteralExpression<>((CriteriaBuilderImpl) criteriaBuilder, pattern));
    }

    public RLikePredicate(
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
        Expression<String> matchExpression,
        Expression<String> pattern,
        Expression<Character> escapeCharacter) {
        super((CriteriaBuilderImpl) criteriaBuilder);
        this.matchExpression = matchExpression;
        this.pattern = pattern;
    }

    public RLikePredicate(
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
        Expression<String> matchExpression,
        Expression<String> pattern,
        char escapeCharacter) {
        this(
            criteriaBuilder,
            matchExpression,
            pattern,
            new LiteralExpression<>((CriteriaBuilderImpl) criteriaBuilder, escapeCharacter)
        );
    }

    public RLikePredicate(
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
        Expression<String> matchExpression,
        String pattern,
        char escapeCharacter) {
        this(
            criteriaBuilder,
            matchExpression,
            new LiteralExpression<>((CriteriaBuilderImpl) criteriaBuilder, pattern),
            new LiteralExpression<>((CriteriaBuilderImpl) criteriaBuilder, escapeCharacter)
        );
    }

    public RLikePredicate(
        CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder,
        Expression<String> matchExpression,
        String pattern,
        Expression<Character> escapeCharacter) {
        this(
            criteriaBuilder,
            matchExpression,
            new LiteralExpression<>((CriteriaBuilderImpl) criteriaBuilder, pattern),
            escapeCharacter
        );
    }

    public Expression<String> getMatchExpression() {
        return matchExpression;
    }

    public Expression<String> getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    public void registerParameters(ParameterRegistry registry) {
        Helper.possibleParameter(getMatchExpression(), registry);
        Helper.possibleParameter(getPattern(), registry);
    }

    @Override
    public String render(boolean isNegated, RenderingContext renderingContext) {
        StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();

        if (renderingContext.getDialect() instanceof HSQLDialect) {
            final String operator = isNegated ? " IS NULL" : " IS NOT NULL";

            buffer.append("rlike (").append(((Renderable) getMatchExpression()).render(renderingContext))
                .append(",")
                .append(escapeSqlRegex(renderingContext, String::valueOf)).append(")").append(operator);

        } else if (renderingContext.getDialect() instanceof MySQLDialect) {
            final String operator = isNegated ? " != 1" : " = 1";

            buffer.append("rlike (").append(((Renderable) getMatchExpression()).render(renderingContext))
                .append(",")
                .append(escapeSqlRegex(renderingContext, String::valueOf)).append(")").append(operator);

        } else {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Unsupported dialect.");
        }
        return buffer.toString();
    }

    private String escapeSqlRegex(RenderingContext renderingContext, Function<Object, String> toStringLiteral) {
        if (!(getPattern() instanceof LiteralExpression)) return ((Renderable) getPattern()).render(renderingContext);
        Object literal = ((LiteralExpression) getPattern()).getLiteral();
        literal = escapeSqlRegex(renderingContext.getDialect(), String.valueOf(literal));
        return "'" + toStringLiteral.apply(literal).replace("'", "''") + "'";
    }

    public static String escapeSqlRegex(Dialect dialect, String regex) {
        if (regex == null) return null;
        if (dialect instanceof MySQL8Dialect) regex = regex.replace("\\", "\\\\");
        return regex;
    }
}
```

I'm expecting a query that shows like
alias.COLUMN RLIKE 'REGEX' in mysql
and regexp_substring (alias.COLUMN, 'REGEX') IS NOT NULL IN HSQL

**FOUND A SOLUTION.**
Is there an better way ?

I finally came up with that solution. The nodeBuilder.function method returns my rlike function. And transform it to an Predicate.
It's not perfect, but I hope it will help someone else.

```
package fr.cstb.doef.dao.expression;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.NodeBuilder;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.SemanticQueryWalker;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.SqmCopyContext;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmExpression;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.expression.SqmFunction;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.AbstractNegatableSqmPredicate;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmNegatablePredicate;
import org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmNullnessPredicate;

import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings({"unused", "WeakerAccess", "UnusedReturnValue"})
public class RLikePredicate extends AbstractNegatableSqmPredicate implements Serializable {

    private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(RLikePredicate.class);

    private final SqmExpression<?> matchExpression;
    private final SqmExpression<?> pattern;

    private final SqmFunction<Integer> function;

    public RLikePredicate(SqmExpression<?> matchExpression, SqmExpression<?> pattern, boolean negated, NodeBuilder nodeBuilder) {
        super(negated, nodeBuilder);
        this.matchExpression = matchExpression;
        this.pattern = pattern;
        function = nodeBuilder.function("rlike", Integer.class, new jakarta.persistence.criteria.Expression[]{matchExpression, pattern});
    }

    public RLikePredicate(SqmExpression<?> matchExpression, SqmExpression<?> pattern, NodeBuilder nodeBuilder) {
        this(matchExpression, pattern, false, nodeBuilder);
    }

    @Override
    public RLikePredicate copy(SqmCopyContext context) {
        final RLikePredicate existing = context.getCopy(this);
        if (existing != null) return existing;
        final RLikePredicate predicate = context.registerCopy(
            this,
            new RLikePredicate(matchExpression.copy(context), pattern.copy(context), isNegated(), nodeBuilder())
        );
        copyTo(predicate, context);
        return predicate;
    }

    public SqmExpression<?> getMatchExpression() {
        return matchExpression;
    }

    public SqmExpression<?> getPattern() {
        return pattern;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> T accept(SemanticQueryWalker<T> walker) {
        if (walker instanceof SqmTranslator<?>) {
            Dialect dialect = ((SqmTranslator<?>) walker).getCreationContext().getSessionFactory().getJdbcServices().getDialect();
            if (dialect instanceof HSQLDialect) {
                return walker.visitIsNullPredicate(new SqmNullnessPredicate(function, !isNegated(), nodeBuilder()));
            } else {
                return walker.visitComparisonPredicate(new SqmComparisonPredicate(
                    function,
                    isNegated() ? ComparisonOperator.NOT_EQUAL : ComparisonOperator.EQUAL,
                    nodeBuilder().literal(1),
                    nodeBuilder()
                ));
            }
        }
        return function.accept(walker);
    }

    @Override
    public void appendHqlString(StringBuilder sb) {
        function.appendHqlString(sb);
    }

    @Override
    protected SqmNegatablePredicate createNegatedNode() {
        return new RLikePredicate(matchExpression, pattern, !isNegated(), nodeBuilder());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd just have to register a custom function that returns a boolean and then you can use that. Something like this in a FunctionContributor:

```java
functionContributions.getFunctionRegistry().registerPattern(
    "rlike",
    "?1 rlike ?2",
    functionContributions.getTypeConfiguration().getBasicTypeRegistry().resolve( StandardBasicTypes.BOOLEAN )
);
```

and then in JPA Criteria you just use `criteriaBuilder.isTrue(criteriaBuilder.function("rlike", Boolean.class, from.get("COLUMN"), criteriaBuilder.literal("REGEX"))))`

Comment: I registered my functionsContributions by creating a file in `src/main/resources/META-INF/services/org.hibernate.boot.model.FunctionContributor` with a line like `full.package.name.PostgresInetSqlFunctionContributor`. Is there any better alternative? Isn't it supposed to be detected automatically?

Comment: This is the "standard" way to do this in Java. There are no alternatives. Also see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html